# Filtration of date not working in mongoldb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

could you please tell me how to filter data by date parameter in MongoDB ?
I do like this
https://mongoplayground.net/p/72LzlP1Sr5W

```
db.collection.find({
  "Att Date": {
    $gte: "2019-01-01",
    $lte: "2019-01-31"
  }
})
```

**current no document showing of this query**

**Expecting**

```
[
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d84330c50d3e4083c7be27b"),
        "Emp No": "A10088P2C",
        "Emp Name": "MANISHA JHA",
        "Card No": "2076",
        "Department": "THBS",
        "Att Date": "03-Jan-2019",
        "In Time": "03-Jun-2019 10:53",
        "Out Time": "03-Jun-2019 18:13",
        "Status": "P       ",
        "Late By ": "01:53",
        "Early By ": "00:00",
        "Total Hour": "07:20",
        "OT Hour": "00:00",
        "Location": "Consolidated",
        "id": "A10088P2C-03-Jun-2019"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d84330c50d3e4083c7be27f"),
        "Emp No": "A10088P2C",
        "Emp Name": "MANISHA JHA",
        "Card No": "2076",
        "Department": "THBS",
        "Att Date": "10-Jan-2019",
        "In Time": "10-Jun-2019 10:32",
        "Out Time": "10-Jun-2019 18:25",
        "Status": "P       ",
        "Late By ": "01:32",
        "Early By ": "00:00",
        "Total Hour": "07:53",
        "OT Hour": "00:00",
        "Location": "Consolidated",
        "id": "A10088P2C-10-Jun-2019"
    },
    {
        "_id": ObjectId("5d84330c50d3e4083c7be284"),
        "Emp No": "A10088P2C",
        "Emp Name": "MANISHA JHA",
        "Card No": "2076",
        "Department": "THBS",
        "Att Date": "17-Jan-2019",
        "In Time": "17-Jun-2019 13:16",
        "Out Time": "17-Jun-2019 18:25",
        "Status": "P       ",
        "Late By ": "04:16",
        "Early By ": "00:00",
        "Total Hour": "05:09",
        "OT Hour": "00:00",
        "Location": "Consolidated",
        "id": "A10088P2C-17-Jun-2019"
    }
]
```

Comment: you need to save the date in date format in the database to match using new Date() or you'll to do exact string match as you are saving date in string which is not recommended(as you can't use date operators in query/aggregate)

Comment: With some cool aggregation [tricks](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZHql_EB7TrW)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend (as mentioned in comments) storing dates as `date object` in the documents to efficiently use date operations and avoid conversions.

To solve this case you can use `aggregation` with [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/), [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/) and `ISODate` conversion.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $addFields: {
      formattedDate: {
        $toDate: "$Att Date"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      formattedDate: {
        $gte: ISODate("2019-01-01"),
        $lte: ISODate("2019-01-31")
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

NOTE: Updated on the mongo playground [link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/O0ezwfwYpcA).

1. `$addFields` will convert `Att Date` to an `ISODate` and pass it on to next stage.
2. `$match` takes that `formattedDate` that is essentially `Att Date` and do a compare with passed dates strings (using `ISODate` conversion).
3. You can remove that `formattedDate` in next stage projection with `$project` if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using Aggregation Pipeline we can get the desired result

1. Project all the required attributes to next stage using [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) 
   In this first projection - Convert Sting date (`Att Date`) into Date object using [$dateFromString](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/)
2. Again use [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and apply condition $gte and $lte on attribute (`Att Date`) to get desired result

Query to achieve the result

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      "Emp No": 1,
      "Emp Name": 1,
      "Card No": 1,
      "Department": 1,
      "In Time": 1,
      "Out Time": 1,
      "Status": 1,
      "Late By ": 1,
      "Early By ": 1,
      "Total Hour": 1,
      "OT Hour": 1,
      "Location": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "Att Date": {
        $dateFromString: {
          dateString: '$Att Date'
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
 {
    $project: {
      _id: 1,
      "Emp No": 1,
      "Emp Name": 1,
      "Card No": 1,
      "Department": 1,
      "In Time": 1,
      "Out Time": 1,
      "Status": 1,
      "Late By ": 1,
      "Early By ": 1,
      "Total Hour": 1,
      "OT Hour": 1,
      "Location": 1,
      "id": 1,
      "Att Date": { "$and": [ {$gte: [ "$Att Date", new Date("2019-01-01") ]}, {$lte: 
     [ "$Att Date", new Date("2019-01-31") ] } ] }
    }
 }
]
)
```